# Mongoose increment value in updateMany operation result NaN

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
  amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  owner: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},
  environment: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Environment'},
  investments: [{
    amount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    roi: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
    code: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Code'}
  }]
});
```

And I want to perform an update operation  to all the objects that has a specific investment.code.
I want to increment the account amount in 2 times the investment done.

Something like that:

```
db.accounts.updateMany({'investments.code':ObjectId("5e7f2a3e20739d171884528f")}, 
{ $inc: { "amount": 'investments.$.amount' * 2 } }
);
```

Result of this is that the records are updated but, account is equals to NaN.
I have tried to convert all to integer by doing this but it doesn't work:

```
{ $convert: { input: "amount", to: "int" } }
```

I want to update the amount field in the root document.
Here is an example:

Imagine I have this account:

```
  amount: 300,
  createdAt  : 12-01-2020,
  owner: "5e7f2a3e20739d1718845256",
  environment: "5e7f2a3e20739d1718845432",
  investments: [{
    amount: 40,
    roi: 0,
    createdAt  : 12-01-2020,
    code: "3"
  },
  {
    amount: 10,
    roi: 0,
    createdAt  : 13-01-2020,
    code: "3"
  }]
```

I want to look for all investments of code 3 and increment the amount of 300 with the double of each investment done, in this case 40*2 and 10*2, the result will be 400 (300 + 80 + 20).

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which amount field do you want to update? The one in the root or the one in the investments array? It would be good if you can explain with sample a sample document, and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, i have added an example. I want to increase the root document.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed the strategy to update these documents (instead using updateMany to use find and forEach clause) and I did:

```
db.accounts.find(  
{'investments.code':ObjectId("5e7f2a3e20739d171884528f")}).forEach(function (account) {
    account.investments.forEach(function (invest) {
        account.amount = account.amount + (invest.amount * 2) ;
    });
    db.accounts.save(account);
 });
```

and it works fine!.

Thanks.